# Ingress Configuration in kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy

I use nginx for reverse proxy purposes. The nginx configuration is responsible for host-name based routing for two backend HTTP services. The nginx performs the TLS termination and reencryption forwarded traffic (both backend services enforce HTTPS). Additionally a couple of headers are set. The used nginx configuration is provided below. How to implement this task via kubernetes ingress? What kind of ingress controller could be recommended for this job? The usage of non-standard ports and different keys seems to make this task not straight forward in nginx-controller. Or I am wrong? Thanks!

```
    server {
      listen 8143 ssl;
      listen [::]:8143 ssl;
      server_name server1.external;
    
      ssl_certificate   /etc/nginx/certs/server1.external.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server1.external.key;
    
      proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    
      location / {
        proxy_pass https://server1.external:8143/;
      }
    
      error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      }
    }
    
    server {
      listen 8085 ssl;
      listen [::]:8085 ssl;
      server_name server2.external;
    
      ssl_certificate   /etc/nginx/certs/server2.external.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server2.external.key;
    
      proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    
      location / {
        proxy_pass https://server2.external:8085/;
      }
    
      error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      }
    }
```

**Implemented solution:** The ports of all to be exposed services have been changed to the same port(> 1024) Nginx-ingress manifests were adjusted manually
(changing of https-port in Deployment and Service objects + https-port command line argument for nginx container)

Comment: any reason behind using the non-standard ports? else it look straight forward to achivce it.

Comment: With standard you mean 443 for https? Ports below 1024 are priveleged. Hence, It will put restriction how to start the application. I can give it a try to uniform using the same port (e.g. 8143) for all backend service. Will it make the exercise easier?

Comment: i am just thinking running nginx on default 80,443 and backend service on any port wont affect us much. correct me if missing anything or misunderstood

Comment: That is not correct. I have at least one service which need to be accessiable under the same port inside and outside of local network.